# error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘struct Fraction *’ and ‘struct Fraction *’)

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a simple program which accepts a numerator and denominator and then divides it and display simplified form. When I compile the program I get the following error and I am unable to understand what the error is:

```
workshop9.c: In function ‘simplify’:
workshop9.c:30:14: error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘struct Fraction *’ and ‘struct Fraction *’)
workshop9.c:31:14: error: invalid operands to binary / (have ‘struct Fraction *’ and ‘int’)
```

Here are the lines where I get the error:

```
 25 void simplify(struct Fraction *var1, struct Fraction *var2) {
 26
 27         int num1;
 28         int num2;
 29
 30         num1 = var1 % var2;
 31         num2 = var2 / 10;
 32 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `operator` `%` on a `structure` in `C`.

Instead access its `member variable` directly which is of `native-type` `integer`.

For example:

```
num1 = var1->somemember % var2->somemember;
num2 = var2->somemember / 10;
```